# Create Table As... with no data in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am using the following query to load data from a file into a table:

```
$ bq query --nouse_legacy_sql 'CREATE TABLE `AZ-163219.bqtesting.%s` 
  AS select * from `AZ-163219.bqtesting.%s_tmp
```

How would I create an empty table using the above query? For other reasons, I need to create the table **from** the file, but I'd like to load the data (in chunks) using an `update` statement later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LIMIT 0`:

```
$ bq query --nouse_legacy_sql '
    CREATE TABLE \`AZ-163219.bqtesting.%s\` AS
    SELECT * FROM \`AZ-163219.bqtesting.%s_tmp\`
    LIMIT 0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use LIMIT 0:

```
CREATE TABLE y
AS
SELECT *
FROM x
LIMIT 0
```